# GCC fortified function documentation

Tags: gcc, fortify-source

I'm trying to find information on what is required for implementing fortified functions in GCC for libc.

From what I understand the __builtin__*_chk variants are for compile-time checks but if GCC can't determine buffer sizes he will replace the call with the __*_chk version if they exist.

Is the above assertion correct? If so where can I find documentation on what is required by GCC in libc to tie together a function to it's runtime __*_chk version when FORTIFY_SOURCE=1|2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortification is mostly implemented in Glibc via GCC's `__builtin_constant_p` and `__builtin_object_size` intrinsics. E.g. here's definition of `memset` from `/usr/include/string.h`:

```
__fortify_function void *
__NTH (memset (void *__dest, int __ch, size_t __len))
{
  if (__builtin_constant_p (__len) && __len == 0
      && (!__builtin_constant_p (__ch) || __ch != 0))
    {
      __warn_memset_zero_len ();
      return __dest;
    }
  return __builtin___memset_chk (__dest, __ch, __len, __bos0 (__dest));
}
```

`__builtin___memset_chk` is simply expanded by GCC to a call to `memset_chk` (also defined in libc.so).

GCC knows about `*_chk` functions but only uses this knowledge to perform optimizations (dead code removal, folding, etc.), not for verification.